# Cannot find where to place files for the Xcode simulator on my Mac

Tags: swift, xcode, uidocumentpicker

I am having trouble finding where to place files on my Mac so that my Xcode simulator sees them.

Working on a "file upload" section for my app. Before I call the UIDocumentPickerViewController, I do call my own function *printSimDir* which I use to open the proper folder on my Mac so I can throw my files in there.

And in there I have three files: *"blank_inv, invoice_001.cvs, and example.mp3"*

However, in my simulator, I don't see these files. I do however keep seeing one xls file that is not any of three above files. So at one point I did get this right.  But not anymore.

I realize that my problem might also be in how I am calling the UIDocumentPickerViewController so am including that code as well.

```
case ButtType.file.rawValue:
    printSimDir()

    let supportedTypes: [UTType] = [UTType.spreadsheet, UTType.commaSeparatedText, .mp3]
    let pickerViewController = UIDocumentPickerViewController(forOpeningContentTypes: supportedTypes)
    pickerViewController.delegate = self
    pickerViewController.allowsMultipleSelection = false
    present(pickerViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)


...


extension UploadInv:  UIDocumentPickerDelegate {

    func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentsAt urls: [URL]) {
    
    for url in urls {
        guard url.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource() else {
            print ("error")
            return
        }
        
        xFile = XFile(fileUrl: url, key: "filename")
        myStartUPButt.isEnabled = true
        
        do { url.stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource() }
        myStatus.text = xFile?.filename
    }
}

func documentPickerWasCancelled(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController) {
    controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

*printSimDir()*

```
func printSimDir(){
    //  tried the commented code as well
    //  let fManager = FileManager.default
    //  guard let url = fManager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first else {return}
    //  print ("\(url)")
    
    #if targetEnvironment(simulator)
    if let documentsPath = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first?.path {
        print("Documents Directory: \(documentsPath)")
    }
    #endif
}
```

Comment: Document picker view controller will copy the selected files (from outside your bundle) to a temporary directory. It has no relation with your documents directory located inside your app

Comment: @LeoDabus Not sure I understand. The document picker works fine on my iPhone. I see all possible files. But easier to do certain debugging on the simulator. So am I looking at the wrong directory in my printSimDir() function?

Answer (score 0):

For those who come across this. Not sure where I found the answer, but it's quite simple.

> Simply drag and drop the files you want from your Mac to the Xcode
> simulator's Home Screen. Currently have only tried them one at a time.

Is this the proper answer? I do not know. But it does work.

Haven't tried every way to do this, (one at a time, multiple files at once, multiple simulators, etc.) But even after a Mac restart the files are still there.